# On the Eigenvalue of Two Equivalent Matrices

Tags: matrices

In linear algebra, we knew that for two square matrices **A** and **B** (over any field $\mathbb{F}$) to be EQUIVALENT, there should exist non-singular matrices **P**,**Q**$\in \mathbb{F}$ such that **A**=**P** **B** **Q**. I am just wondering, are there other not-so-obvious cirumstances for matrices **A** and **B** to have the same eigenvalues, except when **P**$^{-1}$=**Q**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of such examples.

- $I=IAA^{-1}$ where $A\ne I$ is any matrix with all eigenvalues equal to $1$, such as $A=\pmatrix{0&-1\\ 1&2}$.
- Pick any two upper triangular matrices $P$ and $B$ such that $P$ is nonsingular. Let $Q=P^{-1}$. Replace the strictly upper triangular part of $Q$ by other values. With this new $Q$, let $A=PBQ$.
- Let $D=XCY$ where $C$ is arbitrary and $X,Y$ are two nonsingular matrices that are not inverses of each other. Now consider
  $$
  \pmatrix{D\\ &C}=\pmatrix{X\\ &X^{-1}}\pmatrix{C\\ &D}\pmatrix{Y\\ &Y^{-1}}.
  $$
  or more generally,
  $$
  \pmatrix{ZDZ^{-1}\\ &WCW^{-1}}=\pmatrix{ZX\\ &WX^{-1}}\pmatrix{C\\ &D}\pmatrix{YZ^{-1}\\ &Y^{-1}W^{-1}}
  $$
  where $Z$ and $W$ are arbitrary nonsingular matrices. For instance,
  $$
  \pmatrix{0&4&0&0\\ 1&0&0&0\\ 0&0&1&0\\ 0&0&0&-1}
  =\pmatrix{4\\ &1\\ &&1\\ &&&1}
  \pmatrix{0&1&0&0\\ 1&0&0&0\\ 0&0&2&0\\ 0&0&0&-2}
  \pmatrix{1\\ &1\\ &&\frac12\\ &&&\frac12}.
  $$
- In case $\mathbb F$ is of characteristic zero and $B$ is a nonsingular matrix that is not a scalar matrix, we may pick a nonsingular matrix $P$ such that $PB\ne BP$. Then $Q=B^{-1}P^{-1}B\ne P^{-1}$ and we may set $A=PBQ\,(=B)$ or more generally, $A=(S^{-1}P)B(QS)$ for any nonsingular matrix $S$.